# Auf einen Blick vs. auf einem Blick

Tags: grammar

Eine Überschrift soll lauten

> Auf einen Blick

wonach ein paar Statistiken folgen.

Es hat kurz die Diskussion gegeben, ob es nicht

> auf einem Blick

lauten könnte. Nachdem dies natürlich vehement abgestritten wurde, kommt mir diese Variante gar nicht falsch vor. Wenn ich mir beispielsweise das Wort "Alles" vor beiden Varianten vorstelle, scheint mir beides korrekt (auch wenn ich den Akkusativ bevorzuge).

Ist

> auf einem Blick

auch eine mögliche Variante und warum ist sie richtig oder falsch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Richtig ist der Akkusativ.

Die Präposition *auf* wird mit dem Dativ eigentlich nur verwendet, wenn es sich um eine statische räumliche Positionierung handelt. Also die Beantwortung der Frage "Wo?". Siehe dazu auch den canoo.net Artikel [Präpositionen mit zwei Kasus (Dativ und Akkusativ)](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html#Anchor-auf-27347).

> Meist Akkusativ, wenn nicht räumlich

Das bedeutet sicherlich, dass es irgendein Beispiel gibt, wo tatsächlich der Dativ verwendet wird. Das sind in aller Regel feste Verbindungen mit einem Verb. Zum Beispiel [*bestehen auf*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bestehen):

> auf etwas bestehen (meist mit Dativ, seltener mit Akkusativ)

"Auf einen Blick" ist aber Akkusativ und schon immer so gewesen, wie der von Carsten Schultz gepostete Link zum [NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=auf%20einen%20Blick,%20auf%20einem%20Blick&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cauf%20einen%20Blick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauf%20einem%20Blick%3B%2Cc0t1;,auf%20einen%20Blick;,c0;.t1;,auf%20einem%20Blick;,c0t1;,auf%20einen%20Blick;,c0;.t1;,auf%20einem%20Blick;,c0) zeigt.

Answer (score 2):

*Auf einen Blick* und *auf den ersten Blick* sind anders zu analysieren als *mit einem Blick* und *mit dem ersten Blick*. Es handelt sich nicht um eine Standardbedeutung von *auf*, die hier ja anders als *mit* nicht viel Sinn ergeben würde.

Ich würde die Konstruktion vielmehr zusammen mit Wendungen wie *auf einen Tee vorbeikommen*, *auf die Schnelle*, *auf Lehramt studieren*, *auf gut Glück*, *auf jeden Fall* einordnen. Normalerweise kommt sie heute nur noch in solchen relativ erstarrten Wendungen vor, und anscheinend steht sie immer mit Akkusativ. (Wobei der allmähliche Übergang zum Dativ aus Analogiegründen nahe liegt.) Das dürfte die (von mir geteilte) Intuition von kaetschap erklären, *auf* mit Dativ als räumlich gemeint zu interpretieren.

Häufig kann man *auf* hier übrigens weglassen und einfach nur den Akkusativ benutzen. Das klappt z.B. bei *auf einen Augenblick vorbeikommen*, aber nicht bei *auf einen Blick sehen*.